# unable to add connection Visual studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2016

I am trying to add a connection in my VS 2013 file. I have SQL Server 2016 and visual studio 2013 but when I try to add a new connection in VS file this shows me an error

any solution, please

[image]

Comment: I suggest in the first instance that you use a modern version of Visual Studio

Comment: if not then what is the solution? u mean I have to download VS 2017? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Yes. Use a version that is actually supported.

Comment: if i unable to download then how I fix this error ??

Comment: Did it ever work? What of vs project is it? Have you tried repairing the install from programs and features?

Comment: no.. i still ot install or download vs 2017 ... will i downlaod VS 2017 or VS 2019 ?

Comment: Always use the latest version if you gave the choice. So use 2019